# How do I remove files from the application data directory on uninstall?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, winforms, deployment

I have several files and folders that I create in the `Application.CommonAppDataPath` directory during runtime. How can I have my deployment project remove these files on uninstall?

Presently: I have a subclassed instance of `System.Configuration.Install.Installer` that has the `Uninstall` method overridden, but I can find no way to get the application data path of the original application; `Application.CommonAppDataPath` simply returns the path to the Microsoft Installer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to manually go into the application data directory by using the
 `string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData);` then grab all the files you want to delete and delete them manually.

Comment: This looks like a nice solution, though I have to manually append the folders for the company name, application name, and application version. If no other solution comes up, I'll use this one. Also FYI, you had some typos: the correct code is Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData)